# Swift - Property with type and protocol

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In one of my Objective-C clases, I have a property of type `UIViewController<UIProfileListHeaderDelegate>`, how would I represent this in Swift? I need to access properties and methods from both `UIViewController` and `UIProfileListHeaderDelegate`.

Thanks!

Comment: I actually tried it, but I am probably not doing the right search. I thought on using generics, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I also tried creating a typealias, but i couldn't find the right syntax for it.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172430/how-to-declare-a-property-of-a-particular-class-which-is-also-protocol-conforman though no good answer there either. Actually question does not look like easily answerable by Google search

Comment: @codingVoldemort Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: @MarcosDuarte I am very sorry I misunderstood the question. Please edit so it is more clear.
AND, there is NO way you can do this in Swift. I have been coding in Swift for the past few months and it turns out, you just can't do that. It is simply because it's a bad code; it lets your delegate object know more than what is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The swift way to handle this is to define a protocol that includes the relevant methods from `UIViewController` and have your `UIProfileListHeaderDelegate` inherit from that.

Define a protocol with the methods you care about:

```
protocol ViewControllerSubset {
    var view:UIView!
}
```

Declare that UIViewController implements the protocol, don't need to actually implement anything because it's already there

```
extension UIViewController : ViewControllerSubset {}
```

Inherit your protocol from that

```
protocol UIProfileListHeaderDelegate : ViewControllerSubset
```

And away you go.

If you don't want to change the hierarchy of your protocol (or can't because it's a system protocol) you can define a protocol that contains both protocols)

```
protocol EquatableAndComparable : Equatable, Comparable { }
```