# Reference to class that conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Let's say I have a protocol that looks like this:

```
protocol Foo {
    var bar: Bool { get set }
}
```

Now I have my view controller that conforms to the Foo protocol;

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController, Foo {
    ...
}
```

In another class I want to do something like this:

```
class FooClass {

    var viewController: UIViewController? // this should conform to Foo protocol

    func setViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let fooVC = viewController as? Foo {
            // viewController implements Foo protocol
            self.viewController = fooVC
        } else {
            print("ViewController does not conform to Foo protocol")
        }
    }
}
```

In Objective-C I would have a reference that looks like: `UIViewController<Foo> *vc` saying that vc is an object of class UIViewController conforming to Foo protocol. Is there a Swift equivalent?

**EDIT:** I guess it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172430/how-to-declare-a-property-of-a-particular-class-which-is-also-protocol-conforman?rq=1) :(

Answer (score 3):

**Warning**: This solution may become very painful.

As a workaround, you may use *protocol compositions* and eventually *extensions*.

In your example you could be interested only in `UIResponder` protocol methods which `UIViewController` conforms to.

```
typealias FooController = protocol<UIResponder, Foo>

class FooClass {

  var viewController: FooController?

  func setViewController(viewController: FooController) {
    // viewController implements UIResponder and Foo protocols
  }
}
```

But `UIViewController` has properties and methods that does not conforms to any protocol. In this case, you could make a protocol containing the methods that you want and extend `UIViewController`.

```
protocol ViewEvent {
  func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
  func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
  func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
  func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool)
}

extension UIViewController: ViewEvent {}

typealias FooController = protocol<UIResponder, ViewEvent, Foo>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution:

```
typealias FooController = UIViewController & Foo

class FooClass {

    var viewController: FooController?

    func setViewController(viewController: FooController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean.

I don't think you can declare a variable of a given class type **and** conform to a protocol.

However if you just need to check whether `viewController` does conform to the `Foo` protocol (and you don't really need to use the bar property declared in `Foo`) then you could do this.

```
func setViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
    if viewController is Foo {
        self.viewController = viewController
    } else {
        print("ViewController does not conform to Foo protocol")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define as `viewController:Foo?`

Based on our comment you should used `if let fooVC = viewController as? FooViewController`. If you are optional binding the viewController to Foo then assigning it to a UIViewController instance will not work.

Comment: Then I will not be able to use properties and methods from `UIViewController`